# Question: Expansion of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Expand $(A+B)^3(A-B)$ where $A,B$ are matrices.

My try:$$(A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3)(A-B)$$

then I cannot move forward. Can you help me?

Comment: Distributive law?

Comment: Just proceed as you were doing. You'll get a long expression because matrices do not commute, but that's the answer - $8\cdot2=16$ terms long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple expression using distributive law,
$$(A+B)^{3}(A-B)$$
$$=(A^3+A^2B+ABA+AB^2+BA^2+BAB+B^2A+B^3)(A-B)$$
$$=A^4+A^2BA+ABA^2+AB^2A+BA^3+BABA+B^2A^2+B^3A-A^3B-A^2B^2-ABAB-AB^3-BA^2B-BAB^2-B^2AB-B^4$$

Comment: yep i was working on it right now and it looks same. thanks a lot!